# Use constructor in Symfony2 controller

Tags: symfony

I'd like to use a constructor in my Symfony2 controller, but I have this error:

```
ContextErrorException: Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Acme\ApplicationBundle\Controller\CalendarActivityController::__construct() must implement interface Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface, none given, called in /Users/root/Documents/projects/Acme/Symfony/app/cache/dev/classes.php on line 2374 and defined in /Users/root/Documents/projects/Test/Symfony/src/Acme/ApplicationBundle/Controller/CalendarActivityController.php line 16
```

My constructor:

```
public function __construct(Container $container) {
    $this->container = $container;
}
```

I must use a constructor because sometimes I'm using my controller as a service, and in this case container is not defined.

Comment: Guess you should decouple them anyways.

Comment: `(Container $container = null)`?

Comment: His solution got rid of the error message but you will still have problems the first time you try to use the container.  It's not available in the constructor.  You need to use setter injection to inject the container.  More than likely you really want to use a listener instead of a controller.  Plenty of threads on this.

Comment: After reading through the responses my suggestion is hacky… consider the other answers as better advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to inject services into your controller if your controller is registered as a service itself. Read more about it in the official docs: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/controller/service.html

However, let me point out, that there's not much value in injecting the Container. It's much easier to extend the [Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerAware](http://api.symfony.com/2.4/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ContainerAware.html). Symfony will inject the container for you automatically (since `ContainerAware` implements the `ContainerAwareInterface`).

Register your controller as a service if you want to inject specific services.

Use `ContainerAware` otherwise.

Comment: Are you sure about the automatic container injection?  I tried it once but no luck.  I just spell out the setter injection in the services file.  Maybe a tag is needed?

Comment: @Cerad, yes Symfony will inject container into your controller if you make it ContainerAware (implement the interface or extend the ContainerAware class). This is how it works by default in Symfony, also with automatically generated controllers.

Answer (score 0):

you have to call container from dependncy injection use USE

```
    use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface as Container;
      private $container;

public function __construct(Container $container) {
        $this->container = $container;

    }
```